# How do you make dance moves in Roblox studio

Tags: lua

I have tried lots of times to make it work but I just can't do it.

Comment: welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read [ask]. Your post ist of very low quality and will shortly be closed until you improve it

Answer (score 0):

Most "dance moves" are created by using [Animation Editor](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/articles/using-animation-editor) paired with [animation scripts](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/articles/using-animations-in-games). There are a lot of good resources out there to aid you creating one.